# Flutter Position Widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

In Android we can position elements in a linear layout using `LayoutGravity` , I would like to know how to achieve the same in Flutter. I have widgets in a column and I would like some widgets to be position on the left, some on the right and some on the left. How can I achieve this? Here is my code:

```
return new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          //the following textfields must be positioned on the right, but they are on the center
          new Text("Hair cut",),
          new Text("Shampoo",),
          //the button is in the center and that is correct
          new RaisedButton(
            onPressed: ()=>{},
            color: Colors.purple,
            child: new Text("Book",style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Setting `crossAxisAlignment` to `CrossAxisAlignment.end` moves everything to the right. I tried adding the textfields in their own `Column` widget and setting `crossAxisAlignment` to `end` but nothing happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set `crossAxisAlignment` for a generic alignment. And then override it for a specific item by wrapping it in `Align` widget.

```
new Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    //the following textfields must be positioned on the right, but they are not the center
    new Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: new Text("Hair cut"),
    ),
    new Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: new Text("Shampoo"),
    ),
    //the button is in the center and that is correct
    new RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => {},
      color: Colors.purple,
      child: new Text(
        "Book",
        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

You may also want to wrap your `Column` into a `IntrinsicWidth` if you don't want your column to fill the width.

Comment: what if I use Row not Column